# Cython: How do I know when I’m assigning a reference to an object or assigning a copy of an object with the same value?

Tags: cython

In Python, I may have:

```
for k, v in mydict:
    l = v
    l.set_to_one()

print(l._one)

for k, v in mydict:
    print(v._one)
```

and this should print a series of ones (where _one is an integer).

When I do this

```
a=1
b=a
a=2
print(a)
print(b)
```

Will print 2, then 1.

In Cython, if I set the type explicitly or create an object from a Cython extension, how do I know when I’m assigning it a reference or a value via the `=` operator (assume I’m not using external C++ code)? Does it always follow the C rules, or des it occasionally follow Python rules? Does it depend on whether I’m using a Python built-in type like `list` or `dict`?

Answer (score 0):

For anything that is a Python object (i.e. you haven't specified the type, you've specified it to be `cdef object` or you've specified it to be a specific `cdef class`) the rules are exactly the same as Python. Which is mostly by reference, but strings and numbers are immutable. One of the aims is that valid Python code should work the same in Cython, so until you start specifying C types then nothing should change.

For anything where you've specified a C or C++ type the rules will be the same as for C or C++. Things are largely copied "by value", although pointers and C++ `&` references offer ways to pass references too.

Cython automatically works out and fixes a small number of types itself. As far as I know mostly numbers where the variable can obviously only hold a number. Since numbers are immutable and handled "by value" Python this should not affect the behaviour.